# Travis CI saved file locations

Tags: github, ant, travis-ci, checkstyle

I am running the `ant checkstyle` task on my Travis CI whenever a new commit is pushed to my gitHub account. Travis CI is linked to my gitHub account.
When I run the `ant checkstyle` locally on my system a new file is created in my root/checkstyle/checkstyleReport.xml

When this task in getting run on Travis CI it generates the desired xml file, but I have no idea where that file is located. I tried looking into my gitHub account, but there is no sign of this file anywhere on the github. Where do I view this file?
Below is a log from Travis CI:
[image]

Comment: Travis is a cloud service. You must run a task that copies the file from Travis to somewhere you can see it (like, onto your Microsoft OneDrive). Or rather, analyze it on Travis and fail the build if there are issues.

Comment: Does that mean I can't view it anyway?

Comment: `<loadfile property="myFile" srcfile="/myFileName"/> 
<echo message="${myFile}"/>`. This helped to print it in the logs, but has got a character limit perhaps and is definitely not a good idea